# Nearby selection with subChainChangeMoveSelector or subChainSwapMoveSelector

Tags: optaplanner

Is there any way to enable nearby selection in Optaplanner for the subChainChangeMoveSelector or subChainSwapMoveSelector?

I have successfully enabled it for the tail move selector as follows:

```
<tailChainSwapMoveSelector>
            <entitySelector id="tcsm1"/>
            <valueSelector>
                <variableName>prevReq</variableName>
                <nearbySelection>
                    <originEntitySelector mimicSelectorRef="tcsm1"/>
                      <nearbyDistanceMeterClass>NearbyMeterTransportChain</nearbyDistanceMeterClass>
                </nearbySelection>
            </valueSelector>
</tailChainSwapMoveSelector>
```

However, the same config for any of the two chained movemenents returns an XStream error, explaining that neither of them can have a entitySelector.

Comment: To figure out a valid XML - but the docs should really show it in advanced config if they don't - take a look at [SubChainSwapMoveSelectorConfig](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/config/heuristic/selector/move/generic/chained/SubChainSwapMoveSelectorConfig.java#L34) and [SubChainSelectorConfig](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/config/heuristic/selector/value/chained/SubChainSelectorConfig.java#L37)

Comment: @geoffrey-de-smet the problem is that as I understand, I need to specify an entitySelector so I can set the mimicSelectorRef inside the originEntitySelector, and neither SubChainChangeMove nor SubChainSwapMove have an entitySelector property, while TailChainSwap does.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked, the docs chapter "Move and Neighborhood Selection" does document the advanced configuration of subchain change/swap move selectors. Take a look.