# Optaplanner unable to add nearbySelection to subChainSelector

Tags: optaplanner

My question is essentially the same as [Nearby selection with subChainChangeMoveSelector or subChainSwapMoveSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54719539/nearby-selection-with-subchainchangemoveselector-or-subchainswapmoveselector)

I am unable to configure a `<nearbySelection>` for a `subChainSwapMoveSelector` or `subChainChangeMoveSelector`.

The docs outline the use of `nearbySelector` as for example:

```
<tailChainSwapMoveSelector>
        <entitySelector id="entitySelector3"/>
        <valueSelector>
          <nearbySelection>
            <originEntitySelector mimicSelectorRef="entitySelector3"/>
            <nearbyDistanceMeterClass>...CustomerNearbyDistanceMeter</nearbyDistanceMeterClass>
            <parabolicDistributionSizeMaximum>40</parabolicDistributionSizeMaximum>
          </nearbySelection>
        </valueSelector>
</tailChainSwapMoveSelector>
```

However, setting an `entitySelector` on a `subChainChangeMove` or `subChainSwapMove`is not possible due to them lacking an [entitySelectorConfig](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/config/heuristic/selector/value/chained/SubChainSelectorConfig.java#L37). They do support a [valueSelectorConfig](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/config/heuristic/selector/value/ValueSelectorConfig.java), which in turn supports a [nearbySelectionConfig](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/config/heuristic/selector/common/nearby/NearbySelectionConfig.java). However it is impossible to do something like this:

```
<subChainSwapMoveSelector>

 <entityClass>...</entityClass>

 <selectReversingMoveToo>true</selectReversingMoveToo>
     <subChainSelector>
       <minimumSubChainSize>2</minimumSubChainSize>
       <maximumSubChainSize>10</maximumSubChainSize>
       <valueSelector variableName="previousStandstill" mimicSelectorRef="subChainSwapMove">
         <nearbySelection>
           <originEntitySelector mimicSelectorRef="subChainSwapMove"/>
           <nearbyDistanceMeterClass>....</nearbyDistanceMeterClass>
           <parabolicDistributionSizeMaximum>40</parabolicDistributionSizeMaximum>
         </nearbySelection>
       </valueSelector>
      </subChainSelector>
</subChainSwapMoveSelector>
```

Because when ValueSeletorConfig tries to call `buildMimicReplaying()` it fails on

```
if (id != null
                || variableName != null
                || cacheType != null
                || selectionOrder != null
|| nearbySelectionConfig != null
```

Is this a bug? Is there supposed to be an `entitySelectorConfig` for both these moves, or how do I get the `nearbySelection` to work with a `valueSelector` as the docs only outline the use of `entitySelector` ?

Thanks!

Comment: In which docs section is this?

Comment: The examples at nearby selection https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.20.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#nearbySelection